# ProgressDialog on Button click not working android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a button which when clicked should show a ProgressDialog. A API call happenes in the background.

Iam using a `AsyncTask` to talk to the API. I have also place the ProgressDialog initialization in the `onPreExeceute()` and dismiss() in the `onPostExecute()`. But the ProgressDialog does not show as soon as the button is clicked but after 4-5 seconds.

Here is my code:-

```
 case R.id.action_refresh:

            try
            {
                String registerContet = myurl;
                items = new FetchItems().execute(registerContet).get();
                updatedList = new GetList().execute(items).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fragment = new HomeFragment(someparams,updatedList);
            return true;


        private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ProgressDialog myDialog; 

                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //My API call
                        }





            @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            if(refDialog!=null)
                            {
                                refDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }





                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.onPreExecute();


                            if(refDialog!=null)
                            {
                                refDialog =null;
                            }
                            refDialog =  ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "", "Please wait");
                        }




 private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<News>>
            {


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<News> result) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();



                }

                @Override
                protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myNewsList.clear();
    //Some JSON parsing                 


                        }

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return myNewsList;
                }
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: @Haresh it is a ProgressDialog

Comment: where you define it ?

Comment: @Haresh it is defined globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
 new GetList().execute(items).get();
 new FetchItems().execute(registerContet).get();
```

Calling `get()` blocks the ui thread waiting for the result. Just call `.execute(params)`.

You can return the result in `doInbackground` and based on the result returned update ui accordingly in `onPostEecute()`.

Read the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Iam using the AsyncTask somewhere else too. If change anything I get a null result

Comment: @user3713706 You can still get the result. You can have a single asynctask and use interface as a callback to the activity